# the working order of codes at Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, eclipse

I am having problem at printf and scanf lines in the code below.

When i run this code in ECLIPSE.The "scanf" line works befor the "printf" line.But it should not be.Because the "scanf" coming after the "printf".

I run same code in CODE:BLOCKS.It was running right.

How can i fix this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rasyonelSayi{
    int pay;
    int payda;
};

void oku();

int main(void) {
    oku();

    return 0;
}
void oku(){
    struct rasyonelSayi *birsayi;
    struct rasyonelSayi deneme;
    birsayi=&deneme;
    printf("\nrasyonel sayinin payini giriniz:");
    scanf("%d",&birsayi->pay);
}
```

Comment: What you are saying is seem to be wrong. There must be some other issue.

Comment: @haccks, It's not wrong. Its [an issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732) with eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, just add

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

at the start of `main`. The first line causes the `stdout` to be flushed whenever it is written to while the second line does the same for `stderr`.